# How to set Minimum Scroll Displacement value for UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer to fit?

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollviewer, uwp

How to achieve the description mentioned in the below image using UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer in Universal Windows Platform?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `HorizontalSnapPointsType="Mandatory"` on your `ScrollViewer`.

**SnapPointsType** (*HorizontalSnapPointsType* & *VerticalSnapPointsType*)

- **None** No snapping behavior. Only the manipulation influences the final location.
- **Optional** Content stops at a snap point closest to where inertia would naturally stop along the direction of inertia, depending on how
  close the snap point is.
- **Mandatory** Content always stops at the snap point closest to where inertia would naturally stop along the direction of inertia.
- **OptionalSingle** Content stops at the next snap point, if the motion starts far from it.
- **MandatorySingle**  Content always stops at the snap point closest to the release point along the direction of inertia.